# Problema al cargar imagenes en un Recyclerview con firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-glide

soy nueva en android y estoy probando trabajar con firebase el problema que tengo es que cuando cargo las imagenes en un recyclerview se demoran mucho en cargar y no tengo idea de como solucionarlo para mostrar las imagenes estoy usando glide

agredeceria su ayuda

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {
    holder.nombre.setText(listaPlatos.get(position));
   // holder.img.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    storageRef.child("img/"+listaPlatosI.get(position)+".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions().fitCenter().override(50, 50).dontAnimate();
            Glide.with(context).load(uri).apply(myOptions).into(holder.img);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas el código de tu aplicación, haciendo énfasis en donde tienes problemas para que la comunidad acepte tu pregunta y se te pueda ayudar mejor, y como consejo usa librerías como Glide o Picasso, para cargar las imágenes saludos.

Comment: hola mira ese es el codigo con el cual cargo la imagen en el adaptador estoy utilizando glide para cargar el problema es que la imgen la carga muy lento

Comment: Cual es el tamaño de las imágenes que estas almacenando en firebase ??

Comment: la mas pequeña es de 150kb

Answer (score 1):

Esto pasa porque se está realizando una petición a la base de datos por cada iteracion de la lista del recyclerview para obtener la url de la imagen en cuestion, vamos que si tienes por ejemplo 3000 items en tu lista, se haran 3000 peticiones a tu base de datos de firebase.

Lo normal seria que tu lista de items contenga ya las imagenes y solo tengas que cargar cada una en el onBindViewHolder sin tener que obtenerlas de la base de datos, recuerda que el método  onBindViewHolder se ejecuta tantan veces como items hayan en tu lista por lo que en él no debe haber peticiones http, código pesado ni asíncrono.

- El código correcto seria el siguiente: Dando por hecho de que ya tienes declarada y rellenada tu lista de imagenes.

  ```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final 
     ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

      RequestOptions myOptions = new 
      RequestOptions().fitCenter().override(50, 
          50).dontAnimate();
      Glide.with(context).load(miLista.get(position))
          .apply(myOp tions).into(holder.img);
  }
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda lo voy a probar